# A "while" in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have to compare a number with 0 and If it is lower or equal to 0 I have to re-read the number. I've designed a method to read the number before the while condition but it if the number is equal or lower than 0 it doesn't re read the number as it should following the method.

My code looks like this

```
{
char number1[] = "Enter Number(>0):";
char format[] = "%d"; // format string for the scanf function   
int number;
    _asm
        {
            atat:
    lea eax, number1// ask for the number           
    push eax
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    lea eax, number// read it in
    push eax
    lea eax, format
    push eax
    call scanf
    add esp, 8
            //
    while:  
    mov eax, number
    cmp eax, 0
    jg end_while
    jmp atat
    end_while:
```

Comment: Take a look on it in debugger and step over single instructions, what happens. If `mov eax,number` gets compiled as `mov eax,[number]` (Intel syntax), then this should work. So either I don't understand what "doesn't seem to work" means, or it's not compiled as you expect. Also you didn't post how `number` and other variables are defined. And what compiler and target platform you use.

Comment: I'll edit the text in 1 min

Comment: Verify in debugger or objdump or list-file that the opcode for `mov eax,number` is `A1 ....` (`mov eax,[m32]`), and not `B8 ...` (`mov eax,imm32`). And while in debugger, why don't you simply step over it and check out all the values in registers and variables, that would made the exact problem obvious. PS And I would strongly advice you to write `[]` for each memory access, even if your compiler does that automagically for variables.